# Django : no such table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using a ManyToMany relationship using an intermediate table (keyword `through`) in django and I get a `OperationalError at /admin/workoutJournal/workout/add/ no such table: workoutJournal_workoutexercise`

My code is the following :

```
class Exercise(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')

    def __repr__ (self):
        return 'self.name'

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name

    class planesOfMovement(models.TextChoices):
        SAGITTAL = 'SA', _('Sagittal')
        FRONTAL = 'FR', _('Frontal')
        TRANSVERSAL = 'TR', _('Transversal')

    planesOfMovement = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=planesOfMovement.choices,
        default=planesOfMovement.FRONTAL,
    )

    class typeOfMovement(models.TextChoices):
        PUSH = 'PS', _('Push')
        PULL = 'PL', _('Pull')
        CARRY = 'CA', _('Carry')
        LOAD = 'LO', _('Load')

    typeOfMovement = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=typeOfMovement.choices,
        default=typeOfMovement.LOAD,
    )

class Workout(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, through='WorkoutExercise')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

    # class Meta:
    #     db_table = "workoutJournal_Workout_exercises" # necessary to update migrations when modifying the through
    #                                                 # argument of an existing relation

class WorkoutExercise(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    workout =  models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    sets = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    reps = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tempo = models.CharField(max_length = 11, validators=[
                                      RegexValidator(r'[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}', 
                                      message='Please format your tempo as [0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}')
                                  ])
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check the migrations that are generated for these models? Is the intermediate table present in your migrations files?

Comment: Yes I did. And yes, it seems to be the case. Except the name is name='WorkoutExercise' so the case is not identical. But other tables also have this and they work nonetheless

Comment: I had the same problem but was able to fix it: delete all migrations AND drop the database. Then run makemigrations and migrate again. This worked for me, hope it helps you to.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Delete all files in the `migrations` folder except `__init__.py`.
Step 2: Comment out all the fields in models.py, and add some random field, like:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    randomfield = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')

    #def __repr__ (self):
     #   return 'self.name'

    #def __str__ (self):
     #   return self.name
```

Step 3:  Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` in your terminal or CMD.

Step 4: Now remove the random field and uncomment the fields, like:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')

    def __repr__ (self):
        return 'self.name'

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Step 5: Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again.

 
I hope that this should work for you.
Note: Be sure to do this with all models!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried, still not working : no such table: workoutJournal_workoutexercise

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of your models with a few fixes:

```
   class Exercise(models.Model):
        name     = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')

   class Workout(models.Model):
        date       = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
        exercises  = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, through='WorkoutExercise', related_name='workout_exercises')

   class WorkoutExercise(models.Model):
        exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
        workout  =  models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
```